# Why is this not valid code?

Tags: javascript, yui, addclass, yui3, parent-node

I have this piece of code in my javascript file (I'm working with YUI):

```
var levels = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

for(var i = 0; i < levels.length; i++) {
var level = levels[i];
    Y.all(".level"+level).get('parentNode').addClass("category_level"+level);  
};
```

Now, if I have this right in the end of my javascript file, it works fine. However if I have this ahead of other code, none of my other code (functions) work anymore.

I have further isolated the problem to this piece of code: **.get('parentNode')** - When I take that bit out, all the other code and functions work again.

I am not sure, but I think that I might have to something along the lines of:

```
var nodes = Y.all(".level"+level);

nodes.each(function(node){  ...
    node.get('parentNode').......
```

but I am struggling getting this applied to my piece of code at the top.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

This piece of code is not valid for some reason:

```
var levels = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

for(var i = 0; i < levels.length; i++) {
   var level = levels[i];
   Y.all(".level"+level).get('parentNode').addClass("category_level"+level);  
};
```

When I paste this into http://www.jslint.com/ it is so wrong that it cannot even scan it!
"JavaScript syntax error and cannot continue to reliably parse the program"

What is so wrong with this piece of code? It says to "Move 'var' declarations to the top of the function" - but when I do that it just says the same thing again.

Is there perhaps anybody that can tell me what is wrong with that piece of code. Or is it perhaps too difficult or sthing and should be done in an easier way?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked your Javascript console?

Comment: Yeah mate I checked, doesn't seem to be picking up anything wrong there :|

Comment: Ooops, Actually using notepad+ and jslint says 'Stopping (3% scanned)' before it can get to my piece of code in question!

Comment: But checked with online lint thingy and it says that everything is fine

Comment: SOrry Vaughan, have update my question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your HTML looks like, but if you're trying to add a class name to each level, I would use `Y.each` and `Y.one` like so:

```
var levels = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

Y.each(levels, function (level) {
    var node = Y.one(".level"+level);
    if(node) {
        node.get('parentNode').addClass('category_level' + level);
    }
});
```

This would pass in a linter as well as not fail if `Y.one('.level199')` does not exist.

This will work for multiple level nodes:

```
var levels = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

Y.each(levels, function (level) {
    Y.all(".level"+level).each(function (node) {
        node.get('parentNode').addClass('category_level' + level);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Jonas, that was it! The if statement now makes it work because I have indeed some of those levels not present in my HTML. The Y.one() does cuase additional problems now though, because I have more than one place where these classes occur, and this will only add the class to the first one. But this has helped much and I will try to sort the rest out myself ;)

Comment: You are welcome! I updated my answer to accommodate your needs.

Comment: You can call .addClass on a NodeList (http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/NodeList.html#method_addClass). Y.all(".level"+level).addClass("category_level" + level);